# Recover a database accidentally deleted in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, recovery

I have accidentally deleted a dztabase from phpmyadmin plateforme that had no backup copy anywhere. Is there any solution to bring back this database ?

Comment: Afraid not.....

Comment: nope you can't , phpmyadmin is a script can read existing SQL databases in your server , once u delete the database u can't get it back , unless u have backup for the server or try to use a software will help u to restore deleted data if u r on windows . good luck

Comment: Ok you have no database backup. Did you backup the machine the database was stored on?